# How to use \hyperlink (from hyperref) in \makenote (from scrlayer-notecolumn)?

Tags: hyperref, koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage

I am trying to put a `\hyperlink` into a `\makenote`, but I get the following error:

```
! Use of \\makenote doesn't match its definition.
\@ifnextchar #1#2#3->\let \reserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {
                                                           #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\futurelet \@let@token \@ifnch 
l.20 Testing hyperlink \makenote{a \hyperlink{anchorname}{hyperlink}.}
                                                                     in makenote.
```

This is the source code:

```
% lualatex
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{luatex85}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{scrlayer-notecolumn}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Testing makenote \makenote{makenote}.

Testing \hyperlink{anchorname}{hyperlink}.

Testing hyperlink \makenote{a \hyperlink{anchorname}{hyperlink}.} in makenote.

Testing \hypertarget{anchorname}{hypertarget}.

Testing hyperref in makenote \makenote{a \hyperref[labelname]{hyperref}.}.

Testing \label{labelname}label.

\end{document}
```

I use `lualatex` for compilation, but I get the same error if I use `pdflatex` (commenting out `fontspec` beforehand).

The `\hyperlink` command works great in the text, it only fails in the `\makenote`.

The `\hyperref` command works in `\makenote`, but unfortunately the anchors of the `\label`s are not exactly where the `\label`s are defined in general. Therefore this is a solution.

Comment: Untested: `\protect\hyperlink{...}` in `\makenote`?

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, `\protect` solves this problem. Is there a way to define a version of `\hyperlink` that does not need `\protect`? In fact, in my actual use case the `\hyperlink`s are buried in some user defined commands and I have to put `\protect` in front of them if they are used in `\makenote`.

Comment: You can try to `\robustify\hyperlink`, in the preamble, this requires `\usepackage{etoolbox}`

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `etoolbox`. I got it working using `\protecting`.

`\newcommand{\makenoteORmarginpar}[1]{\ifdefined\makenote\makenote{\protecting{#1}}\else\marginpar{#1}\fi}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Since KOMA-Script 3.23](http://www.komascript.de/release3.23) package `scrlayer-notecolumn` has a star variant of `\makenote`, that does not need to protect commands, that may break and should not be expanded:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{scrlayer-notecolumn}[2017/02/08]

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Testing makenote \makenote{makenote}.

Testing \hyperlink{anchorname}{hyperlink}.

Testing hyperlink \makenote*{a \hyperlink{anchorname}{hyperlink}.} in makenote.

Testing \hypertarget{anchorname}{hypertarget}.

Testing hyperref in makenote \makenote{a \hyperref[labelname]{hyperref}.}.

Testing \label{labelname}label.

\end{document}
```

results in

[image]

without error.

You can get the same result (even with KOMA-Script before 3.23) using:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{scrlayer-notecolumn}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Testing makenote \makenote{makenote}.

Testing \hyperlink{anchorname}{hyperlink}.

Testing hyperlink \makenote{a \protect\hyperlink{anchorname}{hyperlink}.} in makenote.

Testing \hypertarget{anchorname}{hypertarget}.

Testing hyperref in makenote \makenote{a \hyperref[labelname]{hyperref}.}.

Testing \label{labelname}label.

\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{scrlayer-notecolumn}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\rhyperlink}{\hyperlink}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Testing makenote \makenote{makenote}.

Testing \hyperlink{anchorname}{hyperlink}.

Testing hyperlink \makenote{a \rhyperlink{anchorname}{hyperlink}.} in makenote.

Testing \hypertarget{anchorname}{hypertarget}.

Testing hyperref in makenote \makenote{a \hyperref[labelname]{hyperref}.}.

Testing \label{labelname}label.

\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{scrlayer-notecolumn}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\rmakenote}[1]{%
  \makenote{\detokenize{#1}}%
}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Testing makenote \makenote{makenote}.

Testing \hyperlink{anchorname}{hyperlink}.

Testing hyperlink \rmakenote{a \hyperlink{anchorname}{hyperlink}.} in makenote.

Testing \hypertarget{anchorname}{hypertarget}.

Testing hyperref in makenote \makenote{a \hyperref[labelname]{hyperref}.}.

Testing \label{labelname}label.

\end{document}
```